# Can I ask questions about resources for certain design elements?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to ask a question that is related to where developers can find certain re-distributable (and completely free) resources over the internet?

The question might become opinion based, but I believe that an answer providing the most comprehensive answer will be best.

Comment: What is the focus of the question(s)? Is it a design topic? Do you have any examples? You have to worry about it being too broad as well, not just opinion based

Comment: have you browsed the many questions we all ready have on this?

Comment: @ZachSaucier The exact questions that I want to ask is: "Where can I find some re-distributable Twitter Bootstrap templates that can be converted to WordPress and uploaded to WordPress.org directory without any legal / license issues."

Comment: that would likely be closed

Comment: @Darth_Vader I did search for "redistributable" but didn't find much on that. Correct me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource questions really do not fit on GD.  We already have some that are outdated but in beta were in scope.  A resource question relies on external links that could go down or the site may not exist after time.  Case in point [How can I start to learn web development?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/463/how-can-i-start-to-learn-web-development).  The OP back 4 years ago asked a valid question and received answers, for its time, were in scope.  Now it was brought back from the dead, and while Zach did leave a great answer his answer will need constant maintenance because the links could and will go down.  Furthermore, the users that did try to assist the OP were downvoted now which I do not ethically agree with but technically on the definition of the downvote it is right.

Another problem I have with them is they are bait magnets for spammers.  Too many fly by users post their site as spam and start posting the same answer over and over to related posts.

---

Reflect on comment:

> Where can I find some re-distributable Twitter Bootstrap templates
>   that can be converted to WordPress and uploaded to WordPress.org
>   directory without any legal / license issues."

I have several issues when I read this:

- could be considered as resource gathering for a particular project
- Relies on external sources
- The answers will become outdated
- Templates are sometimes a disease to designers
- We already have royalty free source questions